# How can I find how many possible combinations there are if i have a bunch or arrays and they print out random items within them?

Tags: math, combinations

So I have a bunch of arrays that print out random strings within them and I want to find out how I can find out how many possible combinations there are. Is there some sort of mathematical formula or something to find that out?

Example:

```
string[] a = { “item1”, “item2”, “item3”, “item4” }

string[] b = { “item1”, “item2”, “item3”}

string[] c = { “item1”, “item2”, “item3”, “item4”, “item5” }
```

Comment: This question is highly unclear. Combinations of what? Do you mean choosing one string from each array? Is {"item1", "item1", "item2"} a combination?

Comment: Okay so what I mean by combination is choosing 1 item out of each array, then printing them. for example it picks out {item4, item2, item5}. What I want to find out is how many possible combinations there are. @Beta

Comment: You multiply the lengths of the arrays together to get the number of combinations.